# html2pdf library is adding border on td instead table

Tags: php, html, css, html2pdf

When I add border on table, it adds border on every td, but I need only to border up table section, is there any way to do this?

Also, is it possible somehow to adjust table width to be 100%, but not inline? Because my table is generated by php and I have no access to inline styles, so it produces the result of table going outside of the main content. I have access to the table class:

```
<style>

.Flex.Standard.FlexTable {
    width: 100%;
}

</style>
```

But it is not working. This width property can be set on table only inline. Maybe someone knows some tricks?

Here is the code:

```
<table style="width: 100%; text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" borderColor="#e2e2e2">
    <tr>
       <td style="width: 50%; padding: 10px;text-align: center;">
           <?php echo '<img src=' . $imageSrc . '>'; ?>
       </td>
       <td style="width: 50%; padding: 10px;text-align: center;">
            <?php echo '<img src=' . $imageSrc . '>'; ?>
       </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're talking about code which is not present in your question. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you tried to add these border="1" and width="100%" table attributes ?

Comment: I have added the code, thank you for your suggestion.